# Must I pre-book bag wrap ar LHR?

Tags: luggage, bookings, lhr

The Excess Baggage Company offers [bag wrapping](http://excess-baggage.heathrow.com/bag-wrap) at Heathrow Airport.  The website links to an online booking form.  Is online booking required, or can I simply turn up at the airport and book a bag wrap on the spot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply show up at the airport. Never seen a queue for bag wrapping at Heathrow.